# Read File line by line using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file line by line using the code below :

```
void main()
{
    cout << "b";
    getGrades("C:\Users\TOUCHMATE\Documents\VS projects\GradeSystem\input.txt");
}

void getGrades(string file){

    string buf;
    string line;
    ifstream in(file);

    if (in.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file error !!!\n";
        return;
    }

    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        cout << "read : " << buf << "\n";
    }

}
```

For some reason it keeps returning "input file error!!!". I have tried to full path and relative path (by just using the name of the file as its located in the same folder as the project). what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this article about Reading Text Files, http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/readtextfile.html. Actually what is wrong here is your escape sequnce

Comment: `void main` is **not standard** and causes compilation errors with many compilers, including g++ in pedantic mode.

Comment: When you did used the relative path, where did you place the file, and how did you run the program?  If you run the program from your file browser or the command line, then file needs to be in the same directory as the executable.  If you did it from within Visual Studio (via Ctrl+F5), then it needs to be in the project directory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I used VS and Ctrl+F5 to run it and the file was in the project folder but for some reason it didnt work!

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach what is the standard version then if I may ask?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi: It should be `int main()`, or `int main(int,char**)`.  Are you sure your file was in the project directory and not the solution directory?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yea you are right it wasnt in the project directory!! my bad... about int main() can you point me to a page where it explains why they use int?? because I remember back when I was learning the basics (about 2 years ago) it was void main()

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi: It was certainly still wrong 2 years ago.  The most reliable resource would be the standard document.  But I don't have it.  But, [here it is](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main) straight from the horse's mouth.  The horse being Bjarne Stroustrup, creator of C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not escape the string. Try to change with:

```
getGrades("C:\\Users\\TOUCHMATE\\Documents\\VS projects\\GradeSystem\\input.txt");
```

otherwise all the \something are misinterpreted.

Comment: Or you could use forward slashes.  They'll still work on windows.

Answer (score 2):

As Felice said the '\' is an escape. Thus you need two.

Or you can use the '/' character.
As windows has accepted this as a directory separator for a decade or more now.

```
getGrades("C:/Users/TOUCHMATE/Documents/VS projects/GradeSystem/input.txt");
```

This has the advantage that it looks much neater.

Comment: Forward slash support was present in original DOS, ca 1981.

Comment: The `'/'` character was a legal directory separator in MS/DOS 2.0.  (Before that, MS/DOS didn't have a directory hierarchy, and there was no separator.)  Early versions of MS/DOS even had an (undocumented) system option which caused the system programs like `dir` to use `'/'` as the directory separator and `'-'` as the option identifier; this was dropped before MS/DOS became Windows, however.

Answer (score 1):

first, if you wanna say '\' in a string, you should put '\\', that's the path issue.

then, the string buf is not in connect to your file..

Answer (score 0):

The backslash in C strings is used for escape sequences (e.g. `\n` is newline, `\r` carriage return, `\t` is a tabulation, ...), thus your string is getting garbled because for each backslash+character sequence the compiler is replacing the corresponding escape sequence. To enter backslashes in a C string you have to escape them, using `\\`:

```
getGrades("C:\\Users\\TOUCHMATE\\Documents\\VS projects\\GradeSystem\\input.txt");
```

By the way, it's `int main`, not `void main`, and you should return an exit code (usually `0` if everything went fine).

Comment: main() is special and does not need a return value. If nothing is returned it will return 0.

Comment: It's not necessary to return an exit code from `main` in C++. C++ `main` returns 0 by default.

Comment: @LokiAstari But it's still cleaner to be explicit, and use the `return EXIT_SUCCESS`.  (Especially as it will usually be something like `return errorCount == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;`.)

Comment: I  wrote "should", not "must". In my opinion you "should" because, when it costs so little, it's better to be clearer, and, since in C89 such a special rule does not exist, it's a good idea to pick this habit to avoid random return values when writing C code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I actually prefer not to put a return when it has no meaning (ie the application always succeeded). If there is a choice and it can fail then adding the return is an indication that it makes a difference.

Comment: @LokiAstari The only way an application can always succeed is if it does no output (since output can always fail).  In which case, what's the purpose of it.  (There are, of course, applications which never terminate, and it does make sense to forgo the `return 0;` in `main` in these.)